# List of Dicts in CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, dictionary

I have a CSV document which has a column where each cell contains a list of dicts. Any advice on how to extract that data while keeping it as lists of dicts would be appreciated. I've tried the usual json/pandas/csv read-ins and none of them seem to work properly (converts to strings/unicode, which isn't surprising but is still frustrating). Ultimately, I'd like the output to be a dataframe, where the header row is the keys and each following row is the data.

Sample CSV Section:

```
1    results

2    [{"y": 47, "type": "square"}, {"type": "square", "b": 49}, {"type": "square", "z": 29}, {"a": 69, "type": "square"}, {"type": "square", "x": 81}]

3    [{"type": "circle", "b": 90}, {"y": 12, "type": "circle"}, {"a": 78, "type": "circle"}, {"type": "circle", "c": 74}, {"type": "circle", "x": 14}, {"type": "circle", "z": 19}]

4    [{"type": "square", "b": 85}, {"type": "square", "x": 73}, {"type": "square", "c": 50}]

5    [{"type": "triangle", "c": 71}, {"type": "triangle", "z": 66}, {"type": "triangle", "x": 16}, {"type": "triangle", "b": 38}, {"y": 67, "type": "triangle"}, {"a": 80, "type": "triangle"}]
```

Sample Output:

```
  type      a   b   c   x   y   z
0 square    69  49  NaN 81  47  29
1 circle    78  90  74  14  12  19
2 square    NaN 85  50  73  NaN NaN
3 triangle  80  38  71  16  67  66
```

Comment: When you have a string like `s = "[{'a': 5, 'b': 3}, {'apple': 'banana'}]"`, you can use `l = ast.literal_eval(s)` and `l` will be a list of dictionaries

Comment: You probably want to have some sample output... it is difficult to see what you are trying to parse

Comment: Put piece of your CSV for example.

Comment: @YounElan updated with ideal output, thanks!

Comment: @Budulianin uploaded a piece of the CSV, appreciate it!

Comment: @PatrickHaugh exactly what I needed. I can turn each "cell" into its own dataframe now, but wasn't able to locate in the docs how to "flatten" it to exist in one row... any insights there? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @shibby, You must post that `column` as text and not images for us to be able to work with it.

Comment: @shibby start with an empty list `l = []` then extend each of the lists you obtain from the csv onto it `l.extend(ast.literal_eval(...))` the make the df from that master list

Comment: @NickilMaveli apologies, updated as text

Comment: @PatrickHaugh perfect. appreciate the assistance!

Comment: You keep using the word "CSV". I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating each line in the file and doing some dictionary work gets you the desired result:

```
with open(filename) as fobj:
    next(fobj)  # skip first line with word `results`
    data = [eval(line) for line in fobj if line.strip()]
res = []
for entry in data:
    d = entry[0].copy()
    for x in entry[1:]:
        d.update(x)
    res.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df.reindex_axis(['type', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z'], axis=1)
df
```

[image]

If you unwanted text on these line. You can remove everything out side the `[]`:

```
eval('[' + line.split('[')[-1].split(']')[0] + ']')
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

eval(re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', line)[0])
```

Comment: thanks mike! this looks awesome, but when I try to run your code I get a syntax error `File "<string>", line 1
    "[{""type"": ""circle"", ""b"": 90}, {""y"": 12, ""type"": ""circle""}, {""a"": 78, ""type"": ""circle""}, {""type"": ""circle"", ""c"": 74}, {""type"": ""circle"", ""x"": 14}, {""type"": ""circle"", ""z"": 19}]",,,,,,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Looks like there are a bunch of extra commas at the end of your line: `19}]",,,,,, `. You need to remove the first.

Comment: Added a line to my answer that should clean the commas away.

Comment: thanks mike - seems to have fixed the commas issue! i'm getting a different error now 

`      6 res = []
      7 for entry in data:
----> 8     d = entry[0].copy()
      9     for x in entry[1:]:
     10         d.update(x)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'`

thanks for the help, i'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Just add a `print(entry)` in line 8 (before the error) to see what you got.

Comment: when i print, it looks as it should `[{y: 47, type: square}, {type: square, b: 49}, {type: square, z: 29}, {a: 69, type: square}, {type: square, x: 81}]`. thanks again for your insight

Comment: But it should look like this `[{'type': 'square', 'y': 47}, `.  Note the quotes around `type` and `square`. Where are the gone?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out mike. i don't really know, i suspect something happened with the `open(file)`, i'm going to do some more research and see if i can't get to the bottom of it. appreciate the help!

Comment: i changed the document from cvs to txt and it works like a charm. thanks again for the help this morning!

Comment: Great. Now, you have the power to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) . ;)